# How can I tell whether a package was installed by dpkg or apt?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I want to remove the package, but I forgot how I installed it through `dpkg` or `apt-get`

I try to check through `dpkg-query -list | grep myPackage` and `apt list --installed | grep myPackage`, but myPackage was shown on both.

so **how can I tell whether the package was installed by dpkg or apt ?**

In order to do the correct uninstall command, like: `apt-get remove` or `dpkg -r`

Comment: You can uninstall either way.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. Compare the log of `/var/log/apt/term.log`, which is the log file generated by `apt` and `/var/log/dpkg.log`, which is the log file generated by `dpkg`. If you note a package name which can be found in `/var/log/dpkg.log` but not in `/var/log/apt/term.log`, it is very likely that you installed the package by `dpkg` that time.
2. Please remember `apt` is a frontend for `dpkg`. Thus, it is recommended to remove any package by `apt` rather than `dpkg`, because `apt` will handle the dependency to remove those packages which will not be used by any other packages (, or mark them as "not use anymore" to let you remove them later. It depends on the exact `apt` options you actually use). However, it is no harm to you to remove your package by `dpkg` if you want. You will just likely leave many packages that you won't use anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @user535733. I edited the answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 21):

Any package installed with APT is also installed with `dpkg`. APT calculates dependencies and fetches the packages, which are then unpacked and installed by `dpkg`.

If you can find your packages with APT, then you should use `apt` commands to uninstall them, because APT will calculate dependencies of the package and:

- remove packages that depend on the package selected for removal
- mark packages that are dependencies of the package selected for removal as no longer needed, so that they can be cleaned up with `sudo apt autoremove`

Answer (score 4):

It does not matter how to uninstall a package.

`dpkg` also requires dependencies that are set in the package.

When you run `apt remove` it starts `dpkg` to remove the package.

When you install a package using `dpkg` and it requires some dependenices, the installation process stops with an error. You can fix it by `sudo apt install -f` that will install dependencies if they are available. In this case `apt autoremove` will work the same way.