# What is the difference between apt and dpkg?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

This is probably a dumb question--I'm pretty new to Linux, so I apologize in advance.

Doing some research for a gestures app, I discovered `libinput-gestures`. [This Medium article](https://medium.com/@kaigo/mac-like-gestures-on-ubuntu-20-04-dell-xps-15-7ea6e3be7f76) suggests that it is compatible with Ubuntu 20.04. I know that I had installed something similar, and now I want to check if that was the one I had installed. With that background, I did some investigating into how to check if packages are installed. I found `apt list --installed` and `dpkg --list`. I know that if I filter down to `apt list --installed | grep lib` I do see a couple of `lib`-type packages, as does `dkpg --list | grep libinput`.

My question is twofold--what are these two package managers used for (clearly they serve different purposes, but [Zanna's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/887154/1103141) suggests that the two operate together in some capacity), and how do I know where to search for a package like `libinput-gestures`?

Comment: Does this website answer your question? You can search for APT there as well.  https://linux.die.net/man/1/dpkg

Comment: Do your searching in apt (See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104592/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-and-dpkg for why). Note that nobody has packaged libinput-gestures for Debian/Ubuntu, so you WILL find [the dependencies](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures), but you WON'T find a package by that name. Neither apt nor dpkg install random github files.

Comment: Related: [Distinction between apt-cache and dpkg -l](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124914/distinction-between-apt-cache-and-dpkg-l)

Comment: The most significant difference from a user POV is probably that `apt` (and `apt-get`) automatically take care of package dependencies. See for example [Do Dpkg and apt-get install dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20031/do-dpkg-and-apt-get-install-dependencies)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between dpkg and aptitude/apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/what-is-the-difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get)

Comment: @Ajay That definitely answers my question about how `dpkg` and `apt` act in tandem, thanks. The follow-up question is, if `apt` essentially manages packages the same way `dpkg` does, and does it better in a way, then why do I see different packages when I run `apt list` vs. `dpkg --list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The question "*What is the difference between apt and dpkg?*" is a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104592/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-and-dpkg.

   Short answer: They do different jobs, and work together. Most of your interaction will be with apt.
2. Your REAL question seems to be "How do I install libinput-gestures?"

   Answer: You follow the install instructions at https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures

   Nobody has packaged libinput-gestures for Debian/Ubuntu, so you will find the dependencies in the Ubuntu repositories and installable by apt, but you WON'T find a package by that name.

   Neither apt nor dpkg install random github files.